# Why won't the background-color of my div appear?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm in process of setting up a drop down menu. I'm trying to get the div `.nav_main` to have the background-color I've given it in my CSS so that it matches the background-color of my burger menu. The `.nav_main` background-color doesn't show up for me for some reason. I know it's trivial but I can't figure out why this is happening...

```css
.nav_main {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
}

.nav_main a {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #282828;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav_main a:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Facilities Portal</h1>
  <div class="nav_main">
    <a class="activeNav" href="index.html">Facilities Info</a>
    <a href="logaction.html">Log Action</a>
    <a href="viewaction.html">View Actions</a>
    <a href="keysystem.html">Key System</a>
    <a id="burgerIcon" class="icon" onclick="#">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

I'm wondering if the `.nav_main a` `display: none` is causing the issue. If so how do I get around this so the div `.nav_main` background-color appears and fills the entire width of the page?

Basically I want `.nav_main` div background-color to appear and fill out the entire width of the page with the burger icon floating to the right. Essentially I'll set the burger up to make `.nav_main a` display change to `block`.

Comment: as you can see here -> https://jsfiddle.net/agovy829/ . It works. Can you replicate the problem ?

Comment: I edited your answer to make a code snippet, tried it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryw5qg9c/1/) as well and it works on both. Something else on your website must be causing the issue, try using devtool's inspector to see what that is. Could be a typo in your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and it works just fine on my end.
What I noticed;

- That you are setting the same color for the `div` as well as the links. This might be the reason you are not seeing a difference.
- You are hiding the links with `display:none` and hence might also not be able to tell which color they are.

You might want to run the code on another machine to make sure the issue is not with your machine.